# Ember: Call a component action from a controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a component working pretty well and now I need to call it inside a controller.

Scenario: I have an ember application, and I have an update button controller, I did a component that just display a toast(Materializecss) with some message I pass as parameter to the component and both the button and the toast are working well separately. I need to call inside the button controller this component to display to the user if the update was successfully or not using this component I did. Any sugestion of how can I call this component inside the controller? Thanks

Comment: You can't "call" a component from the outside. You can pass it an attribute, and then do whatever you want with the attribute, including observing it if you really need to. But a template will automatically observe the attribute and adjust the DOM based on its value.

Comment: thanks for answering but I didnt get well. Supose I have a component called callback-toast.js and inside it I have an action called 'run' that runs the toast on user's screen, also I have a controller called button-controller.js. Inside the button-controller, how can I make a reference to trigger the component?

Comment: You can't. That's not how components work.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b142ed1da1f48d1b78ce5737024e0978?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.material-toast.hbs) I created and see if it fits the bill, in regards to what you want to do ?

You should instead of thinking "calling the component", rather, how can I push updated attributes/data to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Ember relies on the "Data Dow Actions Up" pattern. This implies that you cannot make an explicit call to a component action from a controller. (see https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/14/best-practices-data-down-actions-up for example)

Instead, a better design should be to define a service to manage data : messages to be "toasted". Then make this service available by injecting in in your controller. You will be able to call methods to register a new messages and generate new data.

Provide also a component template (to be included in your own templates) that will be in charge to display the new message, etc. Each change in the data managed by the service will lead to a component template update.

You should definitely take a look to https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-toastr